# Plotting a histogram with Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

For some reason the following line doesn't work:

```
plt.hist(diamonds.price)
```

The following, however, does work

```
diamonds.price.hist()
```

Diamonds is a DataFrame, so why can't I plot it using pyplot.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is unreproducible. What does the program say? Maybe you just should add 'plt.show()' ?

Answer (score 2):

As stated on the Pandas [help](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html),

> The plot method on Series and DataFrame is just a simple wrapper around plt.plot():

The plot needs to know about pandas’s data structures and the `dataframe.hist()` will extract this in the correct manner. If you want to plot using matplotlib, you need to extract the data from the dataframe, something like,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

plt.hist(df.values)
plt.show()
```

Although, this may not plot the data in the same way as using pandas plot methods as you have discarded all the tabular data structure.